# IPhone app builds successfully but will not deploy to device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

XCode decided to mess around with my statically linked library (Three20) so I stripped it out and added using the python script. Now my app builds without any errors but will not actually deploy to the device. It builds and immediately returns "Finished running *application name* on *device name*".  When I try to build on the simulator the outcome is similar except the simulator screen is just completely black.

The device is a iPhone 4 running 5.1 so the 3GS armv6 issue I've found on here is not the answer.  Any ideas how I can rectify this?

Comment: check your debug output window see if you find clue. If not put some breakpoint starting from delegate & your first scene and layer init function see what's going on there...

Comment: Nothing is returned in the debug window and a breakpoint/NSLog inside application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns nothing either :/

Comment: There should be at least some print in xcode debug window. If code has not get into applicationDidFinishLaunching as you said, you put a breakpoint in the main.cpp see where it went wrong.

Comment: Breakpoints in main.m do nothing either. Running on device nothing at all but on simulator outputs 'Program ended with exit code: 0' immediately

Comment: can you post your code ?